# Why are nets defined with directed sets (which only requires upper bound to finite subset)

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders

> The definition of net in topology is defined via a directed set, that is a set $A$ with a preorder such that every finite subset of $A$ has an upper bound.

If my understanding is correct, an ordered set that is directed does not mean every infinite subset has an upper bound. I felt the latter would be more useful if Zorn's Lemma is used in proving a theorem of nets. So is there a reason for not defining this way, and does it really make a difference for all the theorems about nets?

Maybe accepting every subset has an upper bound is too strong, but why do we stick with finite ones, instead of allowing countable, or etc.

Comment: A preorder in which every set has an upper bound has a maximal element, and nets with maximal elements aren't very useful.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I see. Thank you! Then why don't we say countable or other things, why stick with finite?

Comment: @wsz_fantasy Why do you want that? You'd be ruling out the natural numbers, because no infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a supremum.

Comment: @Ningxin Yeah thank you. I guess that's indeed why we limit to the finite case. I forgot what led to this question. Pretty sure I was trying to use Zorn's lemma on something and this popped into my brain

Comment: Since nets were intended as a generalization of infinite sequences, it probably didn't occur to anybody to define them in a way that excludes ordinary infinite sequences.

Comment: @user14111 Your comment should be an official answer.